# File not being passed from view to controller - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

After clicking the submit button, the attachment list object is always null at the controller. Here's the code:

View model:

```
public class CreateTicketViewModel
{
    ...
    public List<IFormFile> Attachments { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="CreateTicket">
...
     <div class="form-group">
          <label asp-for="Attachments" class="control-label">Attachments</label>
          <input asp-for="Attachments" class="form-control" multiple />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
     </div>
</form>
```

Post method declaration:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTicket([FromForm]CreateTicketViewModel createTicketViewModel)
```

All in .NET 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.
The form tag has to have enctype attribute with a value of "multipart/formdata".